# How to delete unwanted records in the Target table in Oracle Data Integrator (ODI)

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

is there any method to delete unwanted rows in the Target table without truncating the Target table?
If any record is deleted in Source table, it will remain in Target table.

I am using IKM Oracle Incremental Update, it handles the Inserts and Updates, but does not handle Deletes.
Is there any way to detect the deleted rows in Source table and then delete them in Target.
Thanks